# why does double return this value? C#

Tags: c#

```
double sth = 250 - 249.99;
Console.WriteLine(sth);
```

Why does this return `sth` like **0.009994507**, instead of **0.01**?

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 1):

Floating point numbers (in this case doubles) cannot represent decimal values exactly.  For more info, see [this page here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

If you need a more accurate representation, use `decimal` instead.

Comment: thank you for your explanation!

Answer (score 0):

because when you print the double you print the all double value not just the first x after point digits.

you can use String.Format to print only the first 2 numbers.

```
        double sth = 250.00d - 249.99d;
        string sthString = String.Format("{0:0.00}", sth);
        Console.WriteLine(sthString);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of decimals that have infinite binary representation. What you're experiencing is exactly this case.

For more on this topic see: http://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/